# Numbering equations as “page number.equation number”

Tags: equations, numbering

How do you get equations numbers of the form "page number.equation number”. Is there a way to set things up so the equation command numbers this way automatically?

Comment: Do you want the equation number to reset with every page?

Comment: You mentioned a problem in your "pseudo-answer" here with solution by @egreg. Note that this problem doesn't occur when my plain TeX solution is used. And you can be inspired by the code if you are not using plain TeX.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using LaTeX, the `perpage` package is what you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just to provide some text

\MakePerPage{equation}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theperpage.\arabic{equation}}

\allowdisplaybreaks % for showing the effect
\begin{document}

\kant*[1]
\begin{equation}
A=B
\end{equation}
\kant*[2]
\begin{gather}
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B\\
A=B
\end{gather}
\kant*[3]
\begin{align}
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B\\
A&=B
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to reset the equation number at each page, replace the two lines

```
\MakePerPage{equation}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theperpage.\arabic{equation}}
```

with

```
\AddAbsoluteCounter{equation}
\MakePerPage{absequation}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theperpage.\arabic{equation}}
```

[image]

Comment: egreg

Thanks. I have been using the \numberwithin command to get the page numbering I want. This works fine for all but two pages. Your idea seems to fix one of those problems but not the other.

Comment: @PaulWalker The cause for your problem is the usage of `eqnarray`. Never ever use it; substitute it with `align` (with `&=&` changed into `&=`, of course) and your life will be better. On the other hand, a footnote marker in an equation is something I can't recommend: in your case it's exactly like an exponent, which is very likely to confuse your readers.

Comment: egreg Thanks for the info on eqnarray. I won't be using it again. As to the footnote in the equation, that is the problem. I think it is the footnote that is messing with the equation counter. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using plain TeX then you can do this:

```
\input opmac \openref

\newcount\flenum
\def\thednum{(\pgref[fle:\the\flenum].\the\dnum)}
\def\eqmark{\global\advance\flenum by1
  \edef\tmp{\pgref[fle:\the\flenum]}%
  \ifx\tmp\lastdpage \global\advance\dnum by1 \else \global\dnum=1 \fi
  \ifinner\else\eqno \fi
  \wlabel\thednum
  \label[fle:\the\flenum]\wlabel{}%
  \thednum \xdef\lastdpage{\pgref[fle:\the\flenum]}
}

\hsize=6cm \vsize=4cm
A test equation:
$$
c^2 = a^2 + b^2. \label[eq1]\eqmark
$$
This is equation~\ref[eq1]. Another test equation, Eq.~\ref[eq2],
is on the next page. But first, another equation:
$$
y=mx+b.  \eqmark
$$
A second test equation:
$$
e=mc^2.  \label[eq2]\eqmark
$$
\bye
```

If you are not using plain TeX, then you can at least be inspired by this macro and you can see, what need to do: You need to declare global counter `\flenum` which is unique for each labeled equation in whole document. This means that it is increased at each label and the label is constructed as `(\pgref[fle:\the\flenum].\the\dnum)`. The destination of `\pgref` must be created at the same page (by `\label[fle:\the\flenum]\wlabel{}` in opmac, for example).

The problem is that the typesetting isn't synchronized by page numbers. If you need to print the right pagenumber, you must to do this via asynchronous `\write` (i.e. via `.ref` file in opmac, `.aux` file in LaTeX etc.).

Edit: I redefined `\eqmark` in order to the eqation number is reset to one at each new page.